# Is there anyway to develop app for android using WPF?

Tags: c#, android, wpf

I know that there is Monodroid for developing in C#.But does it give possibility to use WPF(or something like that) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no WPF support. But however you can use [Adobe Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html) to create Android applications. Flex is a RIA framework.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no support for WPF